# Почему линия выстраивается неправильно?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть код -

```
AX = Convert.ToDouble(AXTextBox.Text);
AY = Convert.ToDouble(AYTextBox.Text);

BX = Convert.ToDouble(BXTextBox.Text);
BY = Convert.ToDouble(BYTextBox.Text);
DrawTriangle(AX, BX, AY, BY);
```

И метод -

```
private void DrawTriangle(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
    {
        if(Canvas.Children.Count >= 1)
        {
            Canvas.Children.Clear();
        }
        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();

        Line line = new Line();

        line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line.X1 = x1*30;
        line.X2 = x2*30;
        line.Y1 = y1*30;
        line.Y2 = y2*30;
        //line.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        //line.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        line.StrokeThickness = 2;
        Canvas.Children.Add(line);
    }
```

Ввожу такие параметры и вот, что рисуется -
[image]

Но ведь должно быть так - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему линия рисуется не правильно? 
Второй вопрос: 
Можно ли потом в canvas добавить текст к линиям, под углом, над линей? Например, чтобы длину линии над ней написать?

Comment: Задавать координаты фигур на канвасе надо с помощью `Canvas.SetLeft` и `Canvas.SetTop` (а лучше `SetBottom`, чтобы отсчет был снизу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все рисуется правильно: просто ордината при рисовании растет вниз, а не вверх, как обычно принято.